# Solitaire: storing guaranteed wins cheaply

Tags: space-complexity, playing-cards

Given a list of deals of Klondike Solitaire that are **known** to win, is there a way to store a reasonable amount of deals (say 10,000+) in a reasonable amount of space (say 5MB) to retrieve on command?  (These numbers are arbitrary)

I thought of using a pseudo random generator where a given seed would generate a decimal string of numbers, where each two digits represents a card, and the index represents the location of the deal.  In this case, you would only have to store the seed and the PRG code.

The only cons I can think of would be that A) the number of possible deals is 52!, and so the number of possible seeds would be at least 52!, and would be monstrous to store in the higher number range, and B) the generated number can't repeat a two digit number (though they can be ignored in the deck construction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given no prior information, the theoretical limit on how compactly you can represent an ordered deck of cards is 226 bits. Even the simple naive 6-bits-per card is only 312 bits, so you probably won't gain much by being clever.

If you're willing to sacrifice a large part of the state-space, you could use a 32- or 64-bit PRNG to generate the decks, and then you could reproduce them from the 32- or 64-bit initial PRNG state. But that limits you to 2^64 different decks out of the possible 2^225+.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking hypothetically, I would say that you would need at least 3.12 MB to store 10,000 possible deals. You need 6 bits to represent each card (assuming you number them 1-52) and then you would need to order them so 6 * 52 = 312. Take that and multiply it by the number of deals 312 * 10,000 and you get 3,120,000 bits or 3.12 MB.

Comment: I just assumed that it would take a massive amount of memory, but that sounds better

Comment: It's less, since each card already "used" reduces the possibility space for the remaining. So the last card, for example, doesn't need to be stored at all, since it can only be one particular one. The second before the last can only be one of 2 cards and required only one bit.